# Accessing Azure Key Vault from JAVA Azure App Service using managed identities

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have a spring boot application deployed in Azure App Service that access Azure Key Vault using User Managed identities.

I have followed the steps mentioned below:

1. Created an User Managed Identity
2. Deployed the spring boot app in Azure App service
3. Added the newly created User Managed Identity to the App service via Identity option
4. Added the User Managed Identity as Owner role under Role Assignments of IAM in App Service
5. Create Azure Key Vault and added a secret to it
6. Added the User Managed Identity under Access Policies of the newly created Key vault with Get, List, Set permissions in Secret Permissions section
7. Added the User Managed Identity as Owner role under Role Assignments of IAM in Key Vault

My Java code to access Key Vault from the application is as follows:

```
MSICredentials msiCredentials = new MSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
msiCredentials = msiCredentials.withClientId("client_id");
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(msiCredentials);
SecretBundle secretBundle = keyVaultClient.getSecret("key_vault_base_url","secret_name");
```

While executing this code in Azure App service deployment, I am getting the following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800677788Z
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800684689Z java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800689989Z  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800695689Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800700989Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800706089Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800711089Z  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800716189Z  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800720890Z  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800725790Z  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800730590Z  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800735490Z  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800740290Z  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800745390Z  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800750191Z  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800755291Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800760191Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800765091Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800769991Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800784292Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800790492Z  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800795392Z  at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800800192Z  at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.MSICredentials.retrieveTokenFromIDMSWithRetry(MSICredentials.java:269) ~[azure-client-authentication-1.6.12.jar!/:na]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800804992Z  at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.MSICredentials.getTokenFromIMDSEndpoint(MSICredentials.java:205) ~[azure-client-authentication-1.6.12.jar!/:na]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800809692Z  at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.MSICredentials.getToken(MSICredentials.java:146) ~[azure-client-authentication-1.6.12.jar!/:na]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800814392Z  at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials.getToken(AzureTokenCredentials.java:74) ~[azure-client-runtime-1.6.12.jar!/:na]
>   2020-02-18T10:21:14.800819093Z  at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.intercept(AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:36) ~[azure-client-runtime-1.6.12.jar!/:na]

Looking at the code of MSICredentials.java in Azure SDK, I could see that the request to following URL - http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/ is getting refused.

Could someone guide me on the settings to get away from this issue? Am I missing any config? Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi Gandhi, could you please have a try with also add your app under Access Policies of the key vault ?

Comment: @HuryShen Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to resolve the issue using system identity and with some code tweaks. Will post the detailed answer shortly. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Gandhi, have you solved the issue ? Could you please share your solution in the answer area ?

Comment: @HuryShen Hi HuryShen, have posted the answer. Please up-vote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue using System Managed Identity rather than User Managed Identity as User Managed Identity doesn't seem to be working with Azure KeyVault currently.

Have created a repo in GitHub that contains the sample code for connecting to Azure resources from AppService using System Managed Identity. The repo link is as follows - [Azure_AppService_ManagedIdentity](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Azure_AppService_ManagedIdentity)

Comment: In your KeyVaultAccessUsingManagedIdentity class, why did you have to do set msiEndpoint and msiSecret ? I thought the whole point of Managed identity was to not have to care about those

Comment: @RomainG I m not setting the value of them. I m just initializing the constant and System.getenv(MSI_ENDPOINT_ENV_VARIABLE) gets the value dynamically from the Azure environment

Comment: But why would you use the overloaded method in that manner? That is what AppServiceMSICredentials(environment) would do (see [there](http://azure.github.io/ref-docs/java/com/microsoft/azure/credentials/AppServiceMSICredentials.html))

Comment: @RomainG AppServiceMSICredentials dint worked for us. Finally the code to get environment variable was suggested to us by Microsoft support after raising a support ticket with them.